# Importing Key Pair into Amazon AWS - wrong fingerprint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to import an existing keypair from my computer to use in EC2. But once I click "Yes, Import", the fingerprint Amazon shows doesn't match the fingerprint shown by `ssh -lf` for the same key. I've verified that they're the same key, tried reimporting the key, etc. The common practice seems to be to use the "Create Key Pair" part instead, but I'd prefer to use my usual SSH keypair. I'm also unable to login using SSH into an instance that's set to use this keypair (I get `Permission denied (publickey).`).

Has anyone encountered such issues with AWS? Any insights into what the issue might be?

Comment: I've added a more detailed answer on ServerFault here: http://serverfault.com/q/603982/102814

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There seems to be [an answer in the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=352828&#352828) for the fingerprint difference. I'm pasting the content here for posterity:

> Hello,
>
> I discussed with my colleagues and looks like it is a limitation from
>   our end to provide keypair in different format. You'll notice the
>   different lengths of the Amazon-generated Key Pair and the Import Key
>   Pair. In the case of an Amazon-generated Key Pair, the Fingerprint is
>   for the Private Key, while if you use Import Key Pair the fingerprint
>   is for your public key. Amazon does not retain a copy of the generated
>   Private Key, but the EC2 command line tools do provide a way to
>   reproduce the SSH2 MD5 fingerprint:
>
> ec2-fingerprint-key ./testpair1-private.pem
>   61:26:cc:7d:2a:2c:a4:e9:fb:86:ca:ef:57:d6:68:f8:24:bc:59:cd
>
> This should match what you see in the console for the region in which
>   you created the key, such as US-West-1 (North California).
>   Unfortunately the ec2-fingerprint-key command-line tool does not
>   fingerprint public keys. If you import the public key in another
>   region such as US-East-1, the web AWS Console will only display the
>   fingerprint of the public key.
>
> Secondly, the **AWS Console should be more clear on exactly what type of
>   fingerprint it displays, which is the "MD5 public key fingerprint as
>   specified in section 4 of RFC4716" (also known as SSH2 format)** as
>   mentioned here:
>
> http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ImportKeyPair.html
>
> We have already put in **a feature request for the web-based AWS Console
>   to support the more common OpenSSH format**. Unfortunately I was not
>   able to find any user-friendly tools to generate the SSH2/RFC4716
>   format fingerprint, though I did find that you can import the same
>   public key in your original region (with a name such as "Test2") and
>   match the shown fingerprint between regions.

(emphases mine)

As he mentions, I too wasn't able to locate any tool to generate the SSH2/RFC4716 format fingerprint. This at least solves the mystery of mismatching fingerprints (at least if we assume `ssh-keygen -lf` gives output in the "more common OpenSSH format", please correct me if this assumption is wrong); I'm still getting a `Permission denied (publickey)` when i try to ssh, but I'll assume it's not an actual key mismatch now and explore other avenues.

Comment: Interesting answer, thanks. By the way, how did you come around the issue (I think you might should have by now)?

Comment: For myself it was forgetting to specify `admin@`... >_<

Comment: Old question, but I had the same Permission denied (publickey) today, and beat my head against it for nearly a half hour...before realizing I'd spun up an Amazon Linux image instead of an Ubuntu image, so the default user was `ec2-user` instead of `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative way to verify finger print:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in my-aws-key.pem -nocrypt -topk8 -outform DER | openssl sha1 -c
```